# Comparison of multiple answers with multiple values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say we have a model `Answer` with the following data:

```
pic_id   | gender | is_nude | has_advertisement
2530     | female | 0       | 1
2530     | male   | 1       | 0
2530     | male   | 1       | 0
2530     | male   | 0       | 1
2530     | male   | 1       | 0
```

How can i get the 3 agreeing answers on all fields (`gender`, `is_nude`, and `has_advertisement`) or `nil` if there is less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aggregation query.  The following gives you all "groups" of answers with their counts:

```
select gender, is_nude, has_advertisement, count(*) as NumAnswers
from Answers
group by gender, is_nude, has_advertisement
```

If you want only the ones that have *exactly* 3 matches, than add the clause:

```
having NumAnswers = 3
```

If you want the one set with the largest, then add:

```
order by NumAnswers desc
limit 1
```